# Sending PDF from jsPDF to controller via ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Guys how can I send the jsPDF file to the controller while also  including  the  model.  I  believe I  have  to change the ajax data: piece, This however is  eluding me.  Any help would  be appreciated.

Model:

```
public class PartialReportModel
{
    public List<ShiftReportDetail> ReportDetails { get; set; }
    public ShiftReport Report { get; set; }
    public byte[] testingImg { get; set; }
    public IFormFile pdf { get; set; }
    public List<UserListsForSignatures> ListOfNames { get; set; }
    public List<ProductCodes> ProductsList { get; set; }
    public List<EquipList> Equipment { get; set; }
    public List<CodeTable> CodeList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditReport(PartialReportModel model,IFormFile Test)
    {
        // do something else here with pdf and model
        return Json(1);
    }
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("click", "#SubmitReportEdits", function () {
var pdf;
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#mod1")).then(canvas => {
    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL(
        'image/png');
    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4', true);
    var width = doc.internal.pageSize.width;
    var height = doc.internal.pageSize.height;
    doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10, width - 20, height - 10);
    pdf = doc.output('blob');
    //doc.save('test.pdf');
});
// ajax the thing
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $("#EditReportForm").attr("action"),
    data: $("#EditReportForm").serialize() + "&Test="+pdf,
    success: function () {
        // close the modal
        // reload the table
        $('#ReviewReport').modal('toggle');
        $('#NotificationDiv').append( // change
            "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show' role='alert'> 
        " + "Report has been edited. Thank you." +
            "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria- 
        label='Close'>" + "<span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>" + "</button>" + " 
        </div>"
        );
     }
  });
});
```

Currently I can see my model stuff but the pdf side is null.
[image]

Comment: Sorry for the confusion KJ.  I am trying to save the PDF file I receive from jsPDF.   I need to store the file in sql server(outside of this question scope).  I however cannot see it on the  post side when ajax sends it to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Because we all have deadlines :/,  I am going to use this method to work this for now  until a  better answer comes along.

First is to convert the file to a base64 string, Then set that to a  value inside the form. Have  a hidden  input to receive the value. This case string pdf.  Then pass it along the ajax.  We now see the value in the controller side. Also have to use jpeg as PNG was too large a file and was getting 413 server errors. Code_debt++

model:

```
public string pdf { get; set; }
```

HTML5:

```
<input asp-for="pdf" hidden/>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).on("click", "#SubmitReportEdits", function () {
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#mod1")).then(canvas => {
    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL(
        'image/jpeg');
    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4', true);
    var width = doc.internal.pageSize.width;
    var height = doc.internal.pageSize.height;
    doc.addImage(imgData, 'jpeg', 10, 10, width - 20, height - 10);
    var pdf = doc.output('datauristring').slice(28); // wipe first28chars
    //saving the base64
    $('#pdf').val((pdf));
    // ajax the  thing
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $("#EditReportForm").attr("action"),
        data: $("#EditReportForm").serialize(),
        success: function () {
            // close the modal
            // reload the table
            $('#ReviewReport').modal('toggle');
            $('#NotificationDiv').append( // change
                "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show' role='alert'> " + "Report has been edited. Thank you." +
                "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>" + "<span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>" + "</button>" + "</div>"
            );
        }
    });
  });
 });
```

Controller Side:
[image]